Using thiserror with [transparent], how do I assert an Error using its original type?
The problem
I'm using thiserror crate to produce a library.
Say I have some code in module A that can generate a range of errors:
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum InvalidGeometryError {
    #[error("Message {0}")]
    TooFewPanelsError(usize),
    #[error("Different Message")]
    BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError(),
}

fn validate_geometry(geometry: &Geometry) -> Result<(), InvalidGeometryError> {

    use InvalidGeometryError::*;

    // ...lots of logic, but for brevity...
    let first_error_condition = false;
    let second_error_condition = true;

    if first_error_condition {
        Err(TooFewPanelsError(1))
    } else if second_error_condition {
        Err(BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError())
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}


Then I use that code in module B, using transparent definition from thiserror to pass through errors:

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Geometry {
    pub stuff: [f64; 2], // Various fields removed for brevity
}


#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum GeometryReadError {
    #[error("Failed to read the geometry file (missing or corrupted?)")]
    FileReadError(#[from] std::io::Error),

    #[error("Failed to parse geometry file contents (is it a valid JSON file?)")]
    FileParseError(#[from] serde_json::Error),

    #[error(transparent)]
    InvalidGeometryError(#[from] InvalidGeometryError),

}

pub fn read_geometry_from_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<Geometry, GeometryReadError> {

    use GeometryReadError::*;

    // Open the file in read-only mode with buffered read
    let file = File::open(path).map_err(FileReadError)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    // Read the JSON contents of the file as an instance of `Geometry`.
    let geometry = serde_json::from_reader(reader).map_err(FileParseError)?;

    // Validate the geometry by passing a reference
    validate_geometry(&geometry).map_err(InvalidGeometryError)?;

    // Return the `Geometry`
    Ok(geometry)
}


When I'm testing, I use a fixture that triggers the BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError:
#[test]
fn panic_on_erroneous_point() {
    let result_or_error = read_geometry_from_file("tests/fixtures/trailing_edge_error.json");

    // assert_err!(result_or_error, Err(InvalidGeometryError::BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError()));
    println!("stop for debug")
    // assert_eq!("the expected error", result_or_error.unwrap_err().to_string());
}

What I want:
Inspired by this SO answer I've played with a few macros but can't get anywhere close (totally new to rust). What I want is to be able to do is assert both what that error currently is, and what it originally was.
My ideal test code:
assert_err!(result_or_error, Err(GeometryReadError::InvalidGeometryError()));
assert_original_error!(result_or_error, Err(InvalidGeometryError::BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError()));

What's confusing me:
If I look at my debugger, it highlights for me that within result_or_error there are two nested entities - the type highlighting (from the image) seems to show correctly, so shouldn't I be able to access that, to get something of the same type as 'InvalidGeometryError::BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError()' and then compare it?
But if I do access result_or_error[0][0] I get something of a different type (the first element of the main error enum).

The question
What would the contents of my assert_err and assert_original_err look like, above?

OK, I'm getting somewhere. I now have a clearer idea of my prior problems writing macros in which I was attempting to match the type.
I've got a macro that does 90% of the job I want, which basically means I can assert error message content, even if the type of the expected error varies from the type of the actual error.

use yfoil::geometry::InvalidGeometryError;
use yfoil::geometry::{read_geometry_from_file};

macro_rules! assert_error {
    ($result_or_error:expr, $expected_error:expr) => {
        // Check it's actually an error first
        if !$result_or_error.is_err() {
            panic!("assert_err failed: expression is not an error")
        }

        // Having confirmed it's an error, check it produces the required string
        let actual = $result_or_error.unwrap_err().to_string();
        let expected = $expected_error.to_string();
        if expected != actual {
            panic!("assert_err failed: error message does not match the expected error\nexpected:   `{}`\nactual:     `{}`", expected, actual)
        }

        // TODO I still have no way of checking how many errors are in the chain 
        // or what their types are
    }
}

#[test]
fn panic_on_erroneous_point() {
    let result_or_error = read_geometry_from_file("tests/fixtures/aerofoil_with_invalid_last_point.json");

    // This will pass...
    assert_error!(result_or_error, InvalidGeometryError::BeginAndEndAtTrailingEdgeError());
    
    // This will barf (of course, because I'm asserting the wrong kind 
    // of error, but using it as proof-of-concept)
    assert_error!(result_or_error, InvalidGeometryError::TooFewPanelsError(1));
    // The output will be:
    //      assert_err failed: error message does not match the expected error
    //      expected:   `The number of panels is too few! Minimum is 1.`
    //      actual:     `First and last points must be at the trailing edge.`

}

